# Changing path in an config file stored in TFS

Tags: tfs

We have a solution stored in TFS that deploys to SharePoint.  As part of the solution we have a config file that has a path to a specific site. The problem is this path changes dependent on the users dev machine e.g

```
<site>devmachine1/somesite</site>
<site>devmachine2/somesite</site>
```

This can obviously be updated to work locally after a check out however when the file gets checked back in it will be incorrect on the next users machine if they do a Get.  Is there a way that the file can be excluded or a script can be run to update the path when checked back in or out?

Answer (score 1):

The best option I'd to rationalist all of the developer workstations.

I would do this by adding an identical entry to the hosts file that hard coded the name of the Sharepoint, allowing you to have the same config file work on every dev machine.

Make it dynamic by having a pre build instruction that adds the host, that way any developer can get and build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom check-in policy to update back the file when is checked-in. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx)